# Update json like structure file in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell script. I have this `swanctl.conf` file. I want to update this file by shell script (`.sh`). I want to update some part or text e.g `remote_addrs, local_addrs` values etc. How can I update file by keeping same format and spaces.

```
# Section defining IKE connection configurations.

connections {

  conn1 {
     local_addrs  = x.x.x.x
     remote_addrs = x.x.x.x

     local {
       auth = psk
       id = local-id
     }
     remote {
       auth = psk
       id = remote-id
     }
     children {
        conn1-child {
          local_ts  = x.x.x.x
          remote_ts = x.x.x.x

          start_action = start
          esp_proposals = aes128gcm128-x25519
          mode = tunnel
        }
     }
     version = 2
     mobike = no
     reauth_time = 10800
     proposals = aes128-sha256-x25519
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly do add your attempts code(there is nothing right or wrong in it, but its encouraged in here). Also add your sample of expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Is this data format home-grown, or is it a "recognized" format that other (non-shell) languages will have modules/libraries for parsing?